# Flutter unable to access class variable set from isolate

Tags: flutter, dart

hello iam learning flutter by creating a chat app, I have the below code which spawns a websocket listener in a isolate, im trying to add the connection to a likedhashmap from the isolate so i can use it to send the reply message to websocket connection, however when i add a entry to the linkehashmap from the isolate and try to access it from sendMessageToChannel function it always returns 0 records, How can i resolve this?

```
  static final BlChatEngine _instance = BlChatEngine._internal();
  static BlChatEngine get instance => _instance;
  BlChatEngine._internal();

  //linked hashmap with all active connections
  LinkedHashMap<String, WebSocketChannel> channels = LinkedHashMap();
  //this function will create a room with clients and join the room if joinRoom is true.
  Stream<String?> createRoom(Friend friend, bool joinRoom) async* {
    final streamController = StreamController<String?>();

    try {
      final CreateRoom requestData =
          CreateRoom(id: friend.email, name: friend.email);
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(ServiceBase.createRoomUrl),
        headers: await ServiceBase.getServiceHeader(true),
        body: jsonEncode(requestData.toMap()),
      );

      ServiceResponse<ChatRoom?> serviceResponse =
          ServiceResponse.parseServiceResponse<ChatRoom?>(
        response.body,
        null,
        (json) => ChatRoom.fromMap(json),
      );

      if (!joinRoom) {
        streamController.add('');
      }

      if (serviceResponse.success) {
        spawnWebsocketIsolate(serviceResponse, false);
      }

      streamController.add(serviceResponse.data?.roomId ?? '');
      streamController.close();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      streamController.addError(e);
      streamController.close();
    }

    yield* streamController.stream;
  }

  //this function will be called on login to create and join private broadcast.
  Future<void> initSubscribeAndRegister() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(ServiceBase.initSubUrl),
        headers: await ServiceBase.getServiceHeader(true),
      );

      ServiceResponse<ChatRoom?> serviceResponse =
          ServiceResponse.parseServiceResponse<ChatRoom?>(
        response.body,
        null,
        (json) => ChatRoom.fromMap(json),
      );

      if (serviceResponse.success) {
        spawnWebsocketIsolate(serviceResponse, true);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  //used to read msg from websocket and spawn isolates for new incoming requests.
  void spawnWebsocketIsolate(
      ServiceResponse<ChatRoom?> serviceResponse, bool initial) async {
    try {
      ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
      ChatRx chatRx = ChatRx();
      //listen to the port
      receivePort.listen(
        (message) {
          print('Received: $message');

          Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = json.decode(message);
          final messageType = jsonMap['type'] ?? '';

          if (messageType == 'text') {
            types.Message blMessage = types.Message.fromJson(jsonMap);
            chatRx.addMessage(blMessage.roomId ?? '', blMessage);
          }

          if (initial && messageType == 'bcast') {
            ChatRoom roomDesc = ChatRoom(
                roomId: jsonMap['text'] ?? '', roomName: jsonMap['text'] ?? '');

            spawnWebsocketIsolate(
              ServiceResponse(
                data: roomDesc,
                success: true,
                returnCode: 0000,
                message: "",
              ),
              false,
            );
          } else {}
        },
      );

      Isolate.spawn(
        registerAndListen,
        [
          receivePort.sendPort,
          serviceResponse.data!.roomId,
          await ServiceBase.getServiceHeader(true),
        ],
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  void registerAndListen(List<dynamic> args) async {
    SendPort sendPort = args[0];
    String roomId = args[1];
    Map<String, String> headers = args[2];

    final wsUrl = Uri.parse(ServiceBase.getSocketUrl(roomId));
    WebSocketChannel channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
      wsUrl,
      headers: headers,
    );
    addChannelToMap(roomId, channel);
    try {
      channel.stream.listen(
        (message) {
          sendPort.send(message);
        },
        onError: (error) {
          sendPort.send(error);
        },
        onDone: () {
          sendPort.send(false);
        },
      );
      // channel.sink.add("test");
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void addChannelToMap(String key, WebSocketChannel channel) {
    try {
      channels[key] = channel;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void sendMessageToChannel(String roomId, String message) {
    if (channels.containsKey(roomId)) {
      channels[roomId]?.sink.add(message);
    }
  }
}
```